# Server disconnect when receive UTF8 character

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**I found how to fix this, I just downgraded both to version 1.4.0 and now it works fine.**

When UTF8 characters are sent through Socket.IO it instantly disconnect, example: á, è, é, ç

I tried to avoid this by replacing all strings but i'm in a position that this is no longer effective

Running Ubuntu 16.04
Socket.io@2.0.4
Socket.io-client@2.0.4

Error after sending special char: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

The error occurred when I sent 'É' on chat

Client Side

```
sendMessage: function(message) {
        if (message === '') return;
        if (this._lastMessage > (Date.now() - this._chatCooldown * 1000)) {
            notify('error', vsprintf(locale.chatCooldown, [((this._lastMessage - (Date.now() - (this._chatCooldown * 1000))) / 1000).toFixed(1)]));
            return;
        }
        this._input.val('');
        this._lastMessage = Date.now();
        socket.emit('chat message', {'type': 'chat', 'message': message});
}
```

Server Side

```
chat.message = chat.message.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
var uniqueID = generate(20);
io.sockets.emit('chat message', {
    message: chat.message,
    profile: {
       avatar: user.avatar,
       rank: user.rank,
       username: user.username
    },
    time: time(),
    uniqueID: uniqueID
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen, and I highly doubt the problem is that simple.  You should show a test case proving the problem and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to verify (proof) that socket.io works fine with non English characters on Linux

Follow the getting started section from here:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

To summarize run the following from your terminal

1. git clone https://github.com/socketio/chat-example.git
2. cd chat-example
3. npm install
4. node index.js

Open a web browser and navigate to localhost:3000

Try using the chat bar at the bottom with non English charters - it will work fine.

Now regarding your question. If something is not working for you it's probably due to your code and misuse of the api.
Follow the docs here:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/README.md

Comment: I did that and worked, so what could be my problem ? I really don't know what to do anymore.